# Generate a unique number out of the combination of 'n' different numbers?

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers

To clarify, as input I have 'n' (n1, n2, n3,...) numbers (integers) such as each number is unique within this set.

I would like to generate a number out of this set (lets call the generated number big 'N') that is also unique, and that allows me to verify that a number 'n1' belongs to the set 'n' just by using 'N'.

is that possible?

Edit:

Thanks for the answers guys, I am looking into them atm. For those requesting an example, here is a simple one:

imagine i have those paths (bi-directional graph) with a random unique value (let's call it identifier):

> P1 (N1): A----1----B----2----C----3----D
>
> P2 (N2): A----4----E----5----D

So I want to get the full path (unique path, not all paths) from A knowing N1 and this path as a result should be P1.
Mind you that 1,2,...are just unique numbers in this graph, not weights or distances, I just use them for my heuristic.

Comment: how are ni choosed? randomly? Is it up to you to choose them?

Comment: What does that mean? Your question is unclear. How `N` is related to `n = {n1, n2, ...}`? What is "by using N" (i.e. using - how and where)? e t.c.

Comment: The question is probably a bit underspecified (and also missing what you have tried), but I suspect [the pigeon-hole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeon_hole_principle) prevents this from being possible, assuming the numbers are all bounded with the same bound.

Comment: Now I am lost. :) What are the numbers in this example? A, B, C or the 1,2,3 or both? What are you trying to save? How big are them? By the way, A1B2C3D isn't already a number?

Comment: The number that uniquely defines the path has to be just as long (asymptotically, in bits) as the path itself. So there's no advantage in doing that.

Comment: @NiklasB. yes indeed, but if just 1-2-3 is the info that must be saved imagining the nodes are exactly 16, there would be no better way than just saving 123 as a number. What I mean is that how long is a path, what are A,B,C and how many/big are they, what are 1,2,3,4, what needs to be saved and.. how long must the resulting number be, and why must it be a number, is all info that changes the problem. And finally why not just save a zipped string? :)

Comment: @FrancescoMM There *is* a better way, and that's just using an array to hold the numbers [1, 2, 3].

Comment: @NiklasB. yes ok, a stream of bits, whatever. I was just expressing that we need more info, that was the point :)

Comment: @FrancescoMM yes i thought about the array :), but was wondering if there is an alternative, since in reality this array would hold 1000+ numbers, but from the input i got so far, i get thats the cheapest solution :)

Comment: @Elio Well somehow the representation you choose has to contain all the information of the sequence. So you won't get away with *much* less than log_2(C) * n bits, where C is the number of different values your elements could take and n is the number of values

Comment: @Elio I have updated my post trying a smaller solution based on the fact that numbers/paths must be unique. This is precious info and must be used to reduce the size, reducing the number of possibilities at every number using a sort of **variable base number**

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing, and your example even worse.  So you have a set `S` of integers, and you want to turn that into a single integer `N` so that you can look at `N` to determine whether a given integer belonged to `S`?  How big can your integers be?  How many are there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are dealing with small numbers, no problem. You are doing the same thing with digits every time you compose a number: a digit is a number from 0 to 9 and a full number is a combination of them that:

- is itself a number
- is unique for given digits
- allows you to easily verify if a digit is inside

The gotcha is that the numbers must have an upper limit, like 10 is for digits. Let's say 1000 here for simplicity, the similar composed number could be:

n1*1000^k + n2*1000^(k-1) + n3*1000^(k-2) ...  + nk*1000^(0)

So if you have numbers 33, 44 and 27 you will get:

33*1000000 + 44*1000 + 27, and that is number N: 33044027

Of course you can do the same with bigger limits, and binary like 256,1024 or 65535, but it grows big fast.

A better idea, if possible is to convert it into a string (a string is still a number!) with some separator (a number in base 11, that is 10 normal digits + 1 separator digit). This is more flexible as there are no upper limits. Imagine to use digits 0-9 + a separator digit 'a'. You can obtain number 33a44a27 in base 11. By translating this to base 10 or base 16 you can get an ordinary computer number (65451833 if I got it right). Then converting 65451833 to undecimal (base11) 33a44a27, and splitting by digit 'a' you can get the original numbers back to test.

**EDIT: A VARIABLE BASE NUMBER?**

Of course this would work better digitally in base 17 (16 digits+separator). But I suspect there are more optimal ways, for example **if the numbers are unique in the path**, the more numbers you add, the less are remaining, the shorter the base could shrink. Can you imagine a number in which the first digit is in base 20, the second in base 19, the third in base 18, and so on? Can this be done? Meh?

In this variating base world (in a 10 nodes graph), path n0-n1-n2-n3-n4-n5-n6-n7-n8-n9 would be

n0*10^0 + (n1*9^1)+(offset:1) + n2*8^2+(offset:18) + n3*7^3+(offset:170)+...

offset1: 10-9=1
offset2: 9*9^1-1*8^2+1=81-64+1=18
offset3: 8*8^2-1*7^3+1=343-512+1=170

If I got it right, in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hx5Aq/ the biggest number path would be: 102411

```
var path="9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0"; // biggest number

o2=(Math.pow(10,1)-Math.pow(9,1)+1); // offsets so digits do not overlap
o3=(Math.pow(9,2)-Math.pow(8,2)+1);
o4=(Math.pow(8,3)-Math.pow(7,3)+1);
o5=(Math.pow(7,4)-Math.pow(6,4)+1);
o6=(Math.pow(6,5)-Math.pow(5,5)+1);
o7=(Math.pow(5,6)-Math.pow(4,6)+1);
o8=(Math.pow(4,7)-Math.pow(3,7)+1);
o9=(Math.pow(3,8)-Math.pow(2,8)+1);
o10=(Math.pow(2,9)-Math.pow(1,9)+1);
o11=(Math.pow(1,10)-Math.pow(0,10)+1);

var n=path.split("-");

var res;

res=
    n[9]*Math.pow(10,0) +
    n[8]*Math.pow(9,1) + o2 +
    n[7]*Math.pow(8,2) + o3 +
    n[6]*Math.pow(7,3) + o4 +
    n[5]*Math.pow(6,4) + o5 +
    n[4]*Math.pow(5,5) + o6 +
    n[3]*Math.pow(4,6) + o7 +
    n[2]*Math.pow(3,7) + o8 +
    n[1]*Math.pow(2,8) + o9 +
    n[0]*Math.pow(1,9) + o10;

alert(res);
```

So N<=102411 would represent any path of ten nodes? Just a trial. You have to find a way of naming them, for instance if they are 1,2,3,4,5,6... and you use 5 you will have to compact the remaining 1,2,3,4,6->5,7->6... => 1,2,3,4,5,6... (that is revertable and unique if you start from the first)

Comment: +1: This seems like the most direct and efficient way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this will definitly help me!

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically, yes it is.

By defining p_i as the i'th prime number, you can generate `N=p_(n1)*p_(n2)*....`. Now, all you have to do is to check if `N%p_(n) == 0` or not.

However, note that `N` will grow to huge numbers very fast, so I am not sure this is a very practical solution.

One very practical probabilistic solution is using [**bloom filters**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). Note that bloom filters is a set of bits, that can be translated easily to any number `N`.

Bloom filters have no false negatives (if you said a number is not in the set, it really isn't), but do suffer from false positives with an expected given probability (that is dependent on the size of the sets, number of functions used and number of bits used).

As a side note, to get a result that is 100% accurate, you are going to need at the very least `2^k` bits (where `k` is the range of the elements) to represent the number `N` by looking at this number as a **bitset**, where each bit indicates existence or non-existence of a number in the set. You can show that there is no 100% accurate solution that uses less bits ([peigeon hole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeon_hole_principle)). Note that for integers for example with 32 bits, it means you are going to need `N` with 2^32 bits, which is unpractical.

Comment: You've got the sense of question? Thumbs up from me